# boost spirit X3 parser which produces offsets into the original string

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I am trying to write a boost::spirit::x3 parser which, rather than producing the sub-strings (for instance), instead produces offsets and lengths of the matches strings in the source.

I have tried various combinations of `on_success` handlers, semantic actions, and nothing has really worked.

given:

```
ABC\n
DEFG\n
HI\n
```

I'd like a parser which produced a `std::vector<boost::tuple<size_t, size_t>>` containing:

```
0,3
4,4
9,2
```

where clearly it gets more complicated as we match specific substrings on each line, rather than just taking the whole thing.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does it help you to search [my answers where I use spirit Qi with boost::string_ref](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+spirit+string_ref+)? The same applies to X3 but the mechanics of semantic actions are - obviously - different in X3. Several answers are very close to what you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick draft.

I've replaced `tuple<p, len>` with a POD struct because the interaction between `x3::raw[]` and `fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp` is such that you need  to specialize `traits::move_to` anyways.

In such cases I hugely prefer a user-defined custom type to specialize on, rather than special casing some generic standard library types that could collide with other uses elsewhere.

So, let the struct be

```
using It = char const*;
struct Range {
   It data;
   size_t size;
};
```

Then, to parse the following sample input:

```
char const input[] = "{ 123, 234, 345 }\n{ 456, 567, 678 }\n{ 789, 900, 1011 }";
```

We need nothing more than a simple grammar:

```
x3::raw ['{' >> (x3::int_ % ',') >> '}'] % x3::eol
```

And a dito trait specialization:

```
namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace x3 { namespace traits {
    template <> void move_to<It, Range>(It b, It e, Range& r) { r = { b, size_t(e-b) }; }
} } } }
```

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/105bea4c6896c4b7)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using It = char const*;
struct Range {
   It data;
   size_t size;
};

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace x3 { namespace traits {
    template <> void move_to<It, Range>(It b, It e, Range& r) { r = { b, size_t(e-b) }; }
} } } }

int main() {
    char const input[] = "{ 123, 234, 345 }\n{ 456, 567, 678 }\n{ 789, 900, 1011 }";

    std::vector<Range> ranges;

    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    if (x3::phrase_parse(
            std::begin(input), std::end(input), 
            x3::raw ['{' >> (x3::int_ % ',') >> '}'] % x3::eol,
            x3::blank,
            ranges)
        )
    {
        std::cout << "Parse results:\n";
        for (auto const& r : ranges) {
            std::cout << "(" << (r.data-input) << "," << r.size << ")\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Parse results:
(0,17)
(18,17)
(36,18)
```

Comment: Why does it fail to compile if I switch the rule inside the raw to `+(~x3::char_("\r\n"))` ?  It goes back to trying to create the Range from a char, rather than move_to'ing it ?

Comment: Seems like the age-old single-element sequence conundrum. It should be gone in the develop branch. Finding the link

Comment: @experquisite Sorry to keep you waiting: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Single-element-attributes-in-X3-still-broken-tp4681549p4683318.html

Comment: Great, thanks!  I am using x3 in boost 1.60 - would this fix get into 1.61 ?