# parsing from std::string into a boost::string_view using boost::spirit::x3

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-x3, string-view

In my [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207141/how-to-improve-performance-of-boostspiritx3-key-value-parser) it was suggested that the performance of my `boost::spirit::x3` parser could be improved by parsing into a `boost::string_view` using the `raw` directive.

However, I have difficulties getting it to compile.
This is what I found out:

- Before `x3`, one had to specialize `assign_to_attribute_from_iterators` (see e.g. [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31345434/678093)) to handle the `raw` directive.
- `x3` now uses the `move_to` free function instead (see e.g. [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37003186/678093)).

I therefore added a `move_to` overload which works if I parse from `char*`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/utility/string_view.hpp>

namespace boost {
namespace spirit { namespace x3 { namespace traits {

template <typename It>
void move_to(It b, It e, boost::string_view& v)
{
    v = boost::string_view(b, std::size_t(std::distance(b,e)));
}

} } }

} // namespace boost

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace parser
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    using x3::char_;
    using x3::raw;

    const auto str  = raw[ +~char_('_')] >> '_';
}

int main()
{
    std::string input = "hello world_";

    boost::string_view str; 
    parse(input.data(), input.data()+input.size(), parser::str, str);

    std::cout << str;
}
```

**[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c06c8ff8ebec885e)**

However, it **does not** compile:

**1) If I parse using `std::string::const_iterator`**

```
parse(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), parser::str, str);
```

The constructor of [`boost::string_view`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/utility/string_view.hpp) either expects a `const char*` or a `std::string&`.

```
main.cpp:12:16: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_string_view(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, std::size_t)'
     v = boost::string_view(b, std::size_t(std::distance(b,e)));
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5638193ef370adf)

How can I instantiate a `boost::string_view` from `std::string::const_iterator`?

**2) If `boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp` is included prior to the `move_to` overload**

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06cfad0b57bde590)

Why is my overload not chosen? Isn't it a better overload than any of those defined in [`boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/move_to.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/move_to.hpp)?
How can I make sure my overload is chosen regardless the order of inclusion?

Comment: 2) is partial ordering. I don't think there is a way around it (I haven't found one before) - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization#Partial_ordering

Comment: @sehe I think it would help if `directive/raw.hpp`  was changed to this: [see here @ line 42-44](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7eeab94a4474ff18), then ADL could be used and the overload would reside in `namespace boost`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd simply write what you want:

```
v = boost::string_view(&*b, std::distance(b,e));
```

You might want to check that storage is contiguous¹ as a concept check for your input range. In that respect, it might be clearer to also require the iterator to be random-access, and write:

```
v = boost::string_view(&*b, e-b);
```

---

¹ this is a requirement for string_view anyways

Comment: can that concept check be done through `Boost Concept Checking`?

Comment: I don't see why not, though I haven't used it.